# Select in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show a select box inside a ng-repeat and am stuck with the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in elements" post-repeat-directive>

    <td>{{element.name}}</td>
    <td>        
    <select ng-model="element.type" 
               ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in tipo_items"></select>
    </select>       
    </td>
</tr>
```

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.tipo_items = [
        { id: 1, name: 'uno' },
        { id: 2, name: 'dos' },
        { id: 3, name: 'tres' },
        { id: 4, name: 'cuatro' },
        { id: 5, name: 'cinco' },
    ];
```

This shows the select items, but no item is pre-selected!
I checked the element.type values and they are correct...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comprehension expression you defined in the `select`, you need to use the `id` value to preselect the item and set it for the `model` object.

```
$scope.element = {};
$scope.element.type = $scope.tipo_items[0].id;
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TWM35/)**</kbd>

Comment: I don´t understand! I can´t change the type, because it is loaded from a database... the type is already an integer between 1-5. I just need it to be selected!

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem...
I was loading the id from the database as json, and the id was a string, not an integer...
this solved the problem:

```
$scope.tipo_items = [
    { id: '1', name: 'uno' },
    ...
```

instead of

```
$scope.tipo_items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'uno' },
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

This is default behavior by angular select directive. If you'll set `ng-model` to a default in the ctrl you'll get it preselected.

something like (in the ctrl):

```
$scope.element.name = $scope.tipo_items[0]
```